# Bash Folder Upload FTP

Tags: bash, upload, ftp, directory, put

I'm trying to upload a folder to my website preferably via FTP and bash, but I can't seem to get this to work. I've installed wput and something called ncftpput and both don't seem to work. I just want to copy the entire folder to a remote server. Here's my folder paths if that will help.

```
ftp.example.com/subdomains/cydia
/theme_builder/upload/
```

Something similar to a put command put for directories would work well. I don't know how to use ftp in bash very well either.
So far this site hasn't failed me yet, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sufficent access to the server to untar a file?

If so i would tar it up, transfer it and untar it.

Comment: I can't do it this way, because this whole thing is supposed to be automated.

Comment: well untaring can be automated, all depends how much access you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ncftpput. Have a look at the -R option (recursive). From the man page:

```
You can upload an entire directory tree of files by using the -R  flag.
   Example:

  $ ncftpput -R pikachu.nintendo.co.jp /incoming /tmp/stuff

   This would create a /incoming/stuff hierarchy on the remote host.
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to do, but I couldn't get it to work. Whenever I tried to use it, it just showed me an equivalent to --help.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use **[`curlftpfs`](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net)** and (with minor caveats[1](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net)) do whatever you'd do on your local filesystem.

Curlftpfs is a fuse filesystem that works on ftp transport like sshfs (or sftp) works over ssh. This way, you can mount a ftp server directory on a local mountpoint like a normal filesystem. You can do all normal opeationsike, e.g. use `find`, `touch`, `cp -r`, `rsync -hxDPavilyzH --stats --delete` or even just `tar`.

**Oh,** I recommend using a suitably protected `~/.netrc` to store the credentials.

[1](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net) some operations will of course be slower than necessary if you don't remember that it's going to use ftp for the transport